# is there a COM API available for Excel Viewer (XLView)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, excel, com

I have developped some code to use Excel (via COM) to prepare a spreadsheet for printing (scaling) and that works fine, but now I'm looking into doing the same thing with only the Excel Viewer.

the problem is that I cant find if it has a COM interface similar to Excel.

I've replaced Excel by XLVIEW in the import statement

```
#import "XLVIEW.EXE" \
    rename( "DialogBox", "ExcelDialogBox" ) \
    rename( "RGB", "ExcelRGB" ) \
    rename( "CopyFile", "ExcelCopyFile" ) \
    rename( "ReplaceText", "ExcelReplaceText" )
```

but now, Excel workspace aren't visible anymore

```
Excel::_ApplicationPtr pApplication;  // Excel namespace not found
```

Comment: This just can't work, the viewer is *not* a substitute for Excel.

Comment: @Hans Passant, the thing is all I need from the ExcelViewer is the capability to set the scaling mode (to fit on 1 page), and print from there. ExcelViewer has that functionality through its GUI, but I'm looking to do the same programmatically ; and I can't find any relevant info if ExcelViewer has such avaiable interface...